# How can I remove my php7.1 from my Ubuntu 18 server?

Tags: apt, package-management, 18.04, php

I tried this:

```
➜  /etc dpkg -l |grep php
rc  php7.1-cli                        7.1.17-1+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+1   amd64        command-line interpreter for the PHP scripting language
rc  php7.1-fpm                            7.1.17-1+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+1   amd64        server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (FPM-CGI binary)
rc  php7.1-json                           7.1.17-1+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+1   amd64        JSON module for PHP
rc  php7.1-mysql                          7.1.17-1+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+1   amd64        MySQL module for PHP
rc  php7.1-opcache                        7.1.17-1+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+1   amd64        Zend OpCache module for PHP
rc  php7.1-readline                       7.1.17-1+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+1   amd64        readline module for PHP
rc  phpmyadmin                            4:4.6.6-5                               all          MySQL web administration tool
```

And then I tried this:

```
➜  /etc apt remove php7.1-cli php7.1-fpm php7.1-json php7.1-mysql php7.1-opache php7.1-readline phpmyadmin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php7.1-opache
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.1-opache'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.1-opache'
```

How can I remove the remaining?

Edit: Sorry for the typo, but I corrected and ran it again. This is what I got:

```
➜  /etc apt remove php7.1-cli php7.1-fpm php7.1-json php7.1-mysql php7.1-opcache php7.1-readline phpmyadmin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package 'phpmyadmin' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'php7.1-readline' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'php7.1-mysql' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'php7.1-fpm' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'php7.1-cli' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'php7.1-json' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'php7.1-opcache' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Looks like PHP is removed already; what makes you think it is not?

Comment: @fkraiem Because from the 1st code block I can still see a bunch of php installed. I fixed the typo but it didn't remove anything. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there's still config files on your system. You can purge the packages with

```
sudo apt purge php7.1-cli ...
```

then they will disappear from dpkg -l

Comment: I tried what you said and it worked! I also did the same thing for all the other items. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

**TL;DR:** The packages that you're looking to remove were already removed (or never installed in the first place).

#### Explanation

If you look at the column headers at the beginning of the output of `dpkg -l` (see below) you'll see that `r` and `c` are shorthands for the desired and the actual package statuses. The explanation of those shorthands is also included in the column title: ***r***emove and ***c***onf-files.

Unfortunately the header is hidden by `grep`, but you can use `dpkg -l '*php*'` to achieve mostly the same effect. As a bonus, columns are abbreviated to allow the table to fit into the width of your current terminal (without output redirection).

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                   Version          Architecture     Description
+++-======================-================-================-=================================================
[...]
```

Comment: _This_ is the correct answer to the question; it shows the OP was trying to remove packages that were already removed. (It might improve the answer to make that more explicit)

Comment: @marcelm: Thanks for your constructive criticism. I agree and hope it's better now.